# benefit of executing bash command

Tags: bash, fedora

What is the benefit of executing `bash` command? In my Terminal Window, nothing visible to the eye happens. I noticed that the `$SHLVL` gets incremented, but beside that I wouldn't know that `bash` was executed. Additionally running `bash --help` doesn't really tell much. I know that bash is one of the shells available, but if you are already using Bourne Again shell, I see no benefits of nesting it. In what scenarios should I execute `bash`?

Comment: `bash` creates a new shell as a child. You can make arbitrary changes to your environment (example, change `$IFS` or unset `$PATH`), and when you exit that child shell those changes disappear with it.

Comment: If you see no change in a terminal window, chances are that you're already running it.

Comment: what are you comparing against? (*not* executing the bash command is one in a long list of things that *aren't* "executing the bash command")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running `bash` by itself if you're already running a `bash` shell only really has one plausible benefit - the new shell will have a "clean" environment (notwithstanding any `export`s).

However, if you're currently running any other shell and want to invoke a `bash` script, and its permissions are not set +x (i .e. executable) with a proper shebang line, you would use `bash /path/to/script.sh` to ensure it runs with the proper shell.

Comment: I shall clarify the wording.

Answer (score 3):

Starting a new shell session with `bash` (or whatever shell you start) sets up a new environment. It will inherit any environment variables<sup>1</sup> from the parent shell session.  Once the new session exits, its environment is destroyed.

Apart from using it as the explicit interpreter to execute scripts (to bypass the `#!`-line in the script itself), or for executing specific commands in a `bash` environment with `bash -c`, starting an interactive shell with just `bash` may be useful for testing things.

I use it all the time since my login shell is `ksh93` rather than `bash`, and so many questions here seems to be about `bash`. Once I've tested whatever it is I wanted to test, I just `exit` (or <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>) and get my trusty `ksh93` session back without any pollution from temporary variables in my environment.

I would do this even if my login shell was `bash`, of course.

In fact, I even have a little shell function I use for initiating a clean `bash` session. It essentially runs `env -i bash` (which starts `bash` without transferring any environment variables to the new session) but also creates a temporary work directory. Upon exiting, the directory is removed by the shell function.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>An environment variable is a shell variable that has been exported.</sub>

---

If anyone is interested:

```
function shell
{
    # Starts the specified shell in a clean environment (save for HOME,
    # TERM and SHELL) and with an empty temporary working directory.
    # The working directory is deleted upon exiting the shell session.
    # If no shell name is given, the shell is infered from $SHELL.

    typeset shell="$( basename "${1:-$SHELL}" )"

    typeset realshell="$( grep "^[^#].*/$shell\$" /etc/shells )"

    if [[ -z "$realshell" ]] || [[ ! -x "$realshell" ]]; then
        printf 'No such shell: %s\n' "$shell" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    tmpcwd="$( mktemp -d "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/shell-$shell.XXXXXXXX" )"
    trap 'printf "Removing %s\n" "$tmpcwd" >&2; rm -rf "$tmpcwd"' EXIT

    printf 'Starting %s in %s\n' "$realshell" "$tmpcwd" >&2

    (
        cd "$tmpcwd" &&
        env -i  SHELL="$realshell" \
                TERM="$TERM" \
                HOME="$HOME" \
                "$realshell"
    )
}
```

Using it (extra newlines inserted for readability):

```
$ shell bash
Starting /usr/local/bin/bash in /tmp/shell-bash.mqUhTkBF

bash-4.4$ ls

bash-4.4$ env
PWD=/tmp/shell-bash.mqUhTkBF
HOME=/home/kk
TERM=rxvt
SHELL=/usr/local/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
_=/usr/bin/env

bash-4.4$ exit
exit
Removing /tmp/shell-bash.mqUhTkBF
```